# Getting the greatest common divisor of a sequence

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> For each positive integer $n$, define $a_n = 20 + n^2 $ and $d_n = \gcd(a_n, a_{n+1})$. Find the set of all values that are taken by $d_n $ and show by examples that each of these values is achievable.

Hello! I hope everybody is doing great! Can anybody help me with the above problem?

I tried some values of $n $ and I think the answer may be $1,3,9$. I thought of using $\mod 3 $ and the fact that a square is congruent to $1 \pmod{3}$ and $20 \equiv 1 \pmod{3}$ but that did not really help.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: How do you guys search for problems so fast? I used Approach0 but could not find anything...

Comment: Funny enough , I had posted the correct answer to that solution.Check it! :)

Comment: Oh I see... Anyways can anybody mark this is as a duplicate.. Thanks :)